# Laravel 5 generate invoice & send it by email in attachment with mpdf

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I am running Laravel 5 project and I created a controller in App->Mail->SendEmail to send emails with an attached system-generated invoice through mpdf, with the below code the invoice is generated but downloaded in my browser before being sent, and when changing the output to be s I get the error "Call to a member function output() on null"

```
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order, $data, $mpdf)
    {
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('invoices.paid_invoice', compact('order', 'data')));
        $fileName = 'Invoice-'.$order->id.'.pdf';
        $mpdf->Output($fileName,"D");
        $this->order = $order;
    }
 
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.send_order')
        ->subject(('my subject'))
        ->attachData($this->mpdf->output(), 'invoice.pdf', [
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',])
        ;
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$this->mpdf` references nothing.

You dont need to use MDF anymore once you created the file so just save the filename and reuse that in the build function

```
private $filename;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Order $order, $data, $mpdf)
{
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('invoices.paid_invoice', compact('order', 'data')));
    $this->filename = 'Invoice-'.$order->id.'.pdf';
    $mpdf->Output($this->filename,"D");
    $this->order = $order;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.send_order')
        ->subject(('my subject'))
        ->attach($this->filename, [
            'as' => 'invoice.pdf',
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and the email is sent with an attachment, but now I have another problem being that the attachment is always broken, no matter if I send it from memory or save it on the server and send it, i have tried to encode the mpdf output but nothing is working, any ideas on how to fix this？

Comment: Not only pdfs, I tried to create a txt file on the fly and it is also corrupted on arrival,

Comment: @beginner that's another question that need a different set of details. like testing the file before sending it and such

Answer (score 2):

As @N69S already mentioned in their answer, the mPDF object is not assigned to the class property. The best would be to avoid any "heavy lifting" in the constructor of the class. You need to call the Output method of mPDF exactly once. You can also create the mPDF object in the build method directly (or use a wrapper for Laravel providing a Facade, if that is your poison).

The main issue with provided examples is that with used second parameter `'D'`, the Output method echoes the PDF content directly (see [$dest in Output method documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html)) and does not return/save anything. You need either:

To save the output to the `$this->filename` property (which can also be a local variable only in your example). This is done with `$mpdf->Output($this->filename, 'F');`,

Or output the binary data of the PDF as a string with `$mpdf->Output(null, 'S');`. If you don't need to save the PDF on your server while generating the invoice, this is the cleanest option.

Based on the variant chosen, the constructor will look like this:

```
public function __construct(Order $order, $data)
{
    $this->data = $data; // define properties for the class
    $this->fileName = 'Invoice-'.$order->id.'.pdf';
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

and the build method will look like this:

```
public function build()
{
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

    $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('invoices.paid_invoice', [
        'order' => $this->order, 
        'data' =>  $this->data
    ]));

    $mpdf->Output($this->filename, 'F');

    return $this->markdown('emails.send_order')
        ->subject(('my subject'))
        ->attach($this->filename, [
            'as' => 'invoice.pdf',
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
        ]);
}
```

or this:

```
public function build()
{
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(/* omitted for readability */);

    return $this->markdown('emails.send_order')
        ->subject(('my subject'))
        ->attachData($mpdf->Output(null, 'S'), invoice.pdf, [
            'as' => 'invoice.pdf',
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
        ]);
}
```

Comment: The question is titled "Laravel 5 generate invoice & send it by email in attachment". Your solution will not (and does not) work anyway, when calling $mpdf->Output($this->filename,"D").